# check files in CMake

Tags: shell

I have a Script.cmake in ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}:

```
add_test(NAME Atest
COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -P ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/script.cmake)
```

and to compare files

```
exec_check(${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E compare_files test1 test2)
```

Comment: Not sure if this is the issue, but your second `exec_check` call is missing the closing variable symbol (`}`) on `${CMAKE_COMMAND`.

Comment: well, `execute_process(COMMAND ${CMD}` is not `execute_process(COMMAND ${CMD} ${ARGN}`. It needs arguments  after command.

Comment: ? When you do `exec_check(diff test_output expected_output)`, what do you think `${CMD}` is? What do you think happens to `test_output` and `expected_output`?

Answer (score 2):

Pass the arguments you want to pass to the command:

```
macro(EXEC_CHECK CMD)
    execute_process(COMMAND ${CMD} ${ARGN} RESULT_VARIABLE CMD_RESULT)
    #                              ^^^^^^^
    if(CMD_RESULT)
        message(FATAL_ERROR "Error running ${CMD}")
    endif()
endmacro()
```

For reference read [cmake documentation function arguments](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/function.html#arguments).

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example for comparing files in CMake. Note how the parameters are passed to the macro:

```
# script.cmake
file(WRITE foo.txt "foo\n")
file(WRITE bar.txt "bar\n")
file(WRITE baz.txt "bar\n")

macro(my_compare_files file1 file2)
        execute_process(
                COMMAND cmake -E compare_files ${file1} ${file2}
                RESULT_VARIABLE _not_the_same)
        if(${_not_the_same})
                message("files are not the same")
        else()
                message("files are the same")
        endif()
endmacro()

my_compare_files(foo.txt bar.txt)       # "files are not the same"
my_compare_files(baz.txt bar.txt)       # "files are the same"
```

You can test it by running:

```
cmake -P script.cmake
```

Returns:

```
Files "foo.txt" to "bar.txt" are different.
files are not the same
files are the same
```